# When would std::is_convertible_v<const type &, type> be false?

Tags: c++, type-traits, std-pair

I was reading the rules of the constructors for `std::pair` (as documented on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair)) when I came across this ruling:

> This constructor is explicit if and only if `std::is_convertible_v<const first_type&, first_type>` is `false` or `std::is_convertible_v<const second_type&, second_type>` is `false`.

`std::is_convertible_v<From, To>` is `true` if `From` is implicitly convertible to `To`, and `false` if that is not the case.

But under what circumstance would a case like `std::is_convertible_v<const T &, T>` be `false`?
I've been thinking about it for a while and I can't actually think of any offhand.
It seems to me that a reference to a const value of type `T` would always be convertible to a value of type `T`.

Comment: I think that might be checking if `T` is copy constructible but if that's the case then why wouldn't it use `std::is_copy_constructible_v`? Maybe it's checking for an explicit copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::is_convertible_v` checks for an *implicit* conversion. `std::is_convertible_v<const T &, T>` returns `true` if there exists an *implicit* copy constructor for `T`.

```
struct S {
  explicit S(const S &) = default;
};
```

`S` has an explicit copy constructor so `std::is_copy_constructible_v<S>` is `true` but `std::is_convertible_v<const S &, S>` is `false`. The copy constructor of `std::pair` should be `explicit` to match the copy constructor of `first_type` so it makes sense that the copy constructor of `std::pair` is `explicit` when `std::is_convertible_v<const first_type &, first_type>` is `false`.